# Navbar-Layout using flexbox: How to position link or paragraph inline/next to menu icon

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am working on a navigation bar at the top of a page. I am using `flexbox` for positioning the elements of the navbar; on the left side I have an animated hamburger menu-icon as well as the page's title, on the right side I have several links. The icon and the page-title are contained in a `<div>`, the links are contained in another `<div>`. Using `flexbox`, `flex-direction: row` and `justify-content: space-between`, I position each  on opposite sides of the page.

In the  on the left side, I want the page-title to be next to the menu-icon. Somehow I cannot figure out to do that, in my code the page title always sits underneath the icon. See this fiddle with the current version of my code (for some reason the animation of the icon is not working in the fiddle, which is not important however for demonstrating my issue):

```js
function changeicon(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-menu {
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav {
  left: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0.4em;
}


/* ----- Nav/Menu Icon  --------------------------------------------- */

.icon-container {
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: all 400ms ease;
}


/*--- Rotation of the first bar */

.change .bar1 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-6px, 6px);
}


/* Fade out the second bar */

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}


/* Rotate last bar */

.change .bar3 {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-6px, -8px);
}
```

```html
<div class="nav flex flex-menu">

  <div class="icon-container" onclick="changeicon(this)">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>

    <a href="">Page Title</a>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a href="" target="blank">Link1</a>
    <a href="" target="blank">Link2</a>
    <a href="" target="blank">Link3</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

How do I have to set up the elements in the `<div>` on the left side so that they appear next to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put title in separate div and push it left with `margin-right: auto`

```js
function changeicon(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-menu {
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav {
  left: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0.4em;
}


/* ----- Nav/Menu Icon  --------------------------------------------- */

.icon-container {
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.page-title {
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: all 400ms ease;
}


/*--- Rotation of the first bar */

.change .bar1 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-6px, 6px);
}


/* Fade out the second bar */

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}


/* Rotate last bar */

.change .bar3 {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-6px, -8px);
}
```

```html
<div class="nav flex flex-menu">

  <div class="icon-container" onclick="changeicon(this)">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="page-title">
    <a href="">Page Title</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="" target="blank">Link1</a>
    <a href="" target="blank">Link2</a>
    <a href="" target="blank">Link3</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: page-title was pushed down by `.bar`-s, which have `display:block`
Now it's in a flex-containter, so it is positioned along main flex axis (horizontal in this case)